# Error multiple properties with the same name in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linqpad

I am working on Linq query and I am getting error on functionNavigation_b.Title column. I am using LinqPad to test my queries initially,

### Error

```
An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name
```

[image]

### LINQ Query

```
from functionNavigation in Sys_Nav_Functions
join functionHierarchy in Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchies on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionHierarchy.Function_ID 
join functionNavigation_b in Sys_Nav_Functions on functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID equals functionNavigation_b.Function_ID
 select new {
              functionNavigation.Function_ID, 
              functionNavigation.Title, 
              functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level,
              functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID, 
              functionNavigation_b.Title 
            }
```

Comment: you have two title columns

Comment: The error is quite self-explenatory, isn´t it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An anonymous object  can't have two properties with the same name.

Change your anonymous projection, give a different name to the second Title property.

```
functionNavigation.Function_ID, 
functionNavigation.Title, 
functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level,
functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID, 
TitleB= functionNavigation_b.Title //or ParentTitle, or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 3):

Error is clear, you have duplicate `Title` name.

Try specifying *unique* name.

```
functionNavigation.Function_ID, 
functionNavigation.Title, 
functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level,
functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID, 
AnotherTitle= functionNavigation_b.Title
```